# How does a spectrum analyzer works. Example with particular case: eyes

Tags: waves, fourier-transform, biophysics, signal-processing, perception

[edit]: I reformulated my question to first talk about general spectrum analyzer and then ask about how vision works (which is a particular case of spectrum analyzer as I explain below).

Let's assume we have a sensor that needs to analyze a spectrum of a signal $f(t)$. In theory, to find the Fourier spectrum of a signal, the calculation must occur for an infinite time as given by the following formula:

$$\widehat{f}(\omega)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} d t'  f(t') e^{j \omega t'}$$

Thus, in practice, I guess that to measure the spectrum of a signal, the device doing so will actually compute something like:

$$\widehat{f}(t,\omega)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} d t'  W_t(t') f(t') e^{j \omega t'}$$

Where $t$ is the moment at which I look at the spectrum of the signal, $W_t(t')$ must be at least be function that vanishes for $t'>t$. Then, when I will look at the spectrum, as defined as this last function, it will vary in time.

I just have read that this kind of thing is called time-frequency representation but I don't know much about it.

Now, my question related to it is the following:

- How is properly modelled the output of a spectrum analyzer ? It cannot be the mapping $f(t) \rightarrow \widehat{f}(\omega)$ because as explained above it would require to measure for an infinite amount of time. I would like to clarify way to model it in the most clean way.

Now, I introduce my next very related question.

My original question was actually about how eyes/ear do work. And it is very related to my question about sensors. Let me first convince that this question is definitely about physics.

If I see something that is blue, it necesseraly mean that all the process from the light signal $f(t)$ to what I am conscious about "it is blue", my brain was able to extract the information "the frequencies that composes the signal are around $440 nm$". **Thus, the brain+eye is basically a spectrum analyzer**.

If you do not agree with this, **please tell me why**. For me if we say that brain+eye is not a spectrum analyzer it means we couldn't see any color as we associate a sensation to a wavelength, and that to know if a wavelength is present we basically have to access the spectrum of the incoming signal.

What disturbs me is that if there is a light blinking, like I turn on and off a red laser. I will still see each time the laser is turned on a red light. And this confuses me a lot. Indeed, by doing so we add some frequencies (to turn on/off the laser adds frequencies in its signal, in a way the light emitted is no longer monochromatic). But in practice any color emitter that blinks, even fast, we always see it the same color.

Thus, in my second question I would like to understand this under a signal processing angle. Why do color always look the same even if something blinks ? As a related question, why by continuously looking at a color, I don't see this color changing. What would that mean in term of mathematical description of the system eyes+brain as being the spectrum analyzer ?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about physics.

Comment: How does a piano string produce a certain frequency? After all, the string doesn't continue to vibrate for infinite time. Hint: if we can observe a signal for a finite length of time, we can estimate its frequency approximately, with uncertainty inversely proportional to the duration of the observation.

Comment: @CharlesFrancis it is definitely about physics. I am talking about signal processing and how sensor physically works.

Comment: @ThePhoton yes I guess so but that means that our perception of color and sound would depend on the duration at which we listen/look at them. I find it perturbing. Maybe it is the case (but the effect is very weak) but I would like to check it.

Comment: @ThePhoton For instance, imagine a signal which is $f(t)=e^{i \omega t}$ (we can check it by looking at it during an infinite time, before we cannot know this). As this signal for infinite time is extremly sharp in frequency I would expect that when I listen to it my perception of the tone varies along the time. Is it really the case ?

Comment: It is definitely not about physics. The ear converts a sound wave into an electromagnetic signal which is interpreted by the brain. We don't know how that works, but the brain recognises and interprets the frequencies in the signal. Suggesting that it might use an FT is a wild speculation, and also off-topic a personal theory

Comment: @CharlesFrancis if the brain is able to distinguish between two situation it means there is a physical difference between them. Replace ear/eye by sensor if you wish, it is the exact same question: how a sensor can tell me which frequency I have in a signal. In addition to that there is a biophysic topic on this site and this question would definitely fit in.

Comment: FYI: There's no "frequency" in any description of how your eyes recognize different colors. It's the _energy_ of a photon that determines the probability of it being "detected" by one of the several different kinds of light-sensitive molecule in your eye.

Comment: @SolomonSlow I don't think we need to talk about photons (and thus going into a quantum description) to understand the process. But even if we need, because $E=\hbar \omega$ there is the same problem, to accurately determine the energy of a photon you must measure for long enough.

Comment: @StarBucK,There are [specific protein molecules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opsin) in the photo receptor cells in your retinas that respond to light. You can search up the literature that explains what we know of how they work, and you can find out for yourself whether it talks about frequencies and Fourier transforms, or whether it talks about molecular orbitals, photons, allowed and forbidden energy bands, etc.

Comment: @StarBucK Since there seems to be an issue with this question being about physics or biology, and since you have stated yourself that you are more just interested in sensors in general, then I would suggest just editing the question to talk about sensors and not about eyes, ears, etc.

Comment: @BioPhysicist I will update my question later on as you suggest to focus on sensor.

Comment: @BioPhysicist I edited

Answer (score 2):

See the question [*Which transform most closely mimics the human auditory system?*](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/38817/which-transform-most-closely-mimics-the-human-auditory-system) on the Signal Processing SE. In short, the ear has a [filter bank](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filter_bank) of [gammatone-like filters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gammatone_filter) tuned to different frequencies:

[image]

The [impulse response function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impulse_response) of an individual filter looks something like this:

[image]

Notice the impulse response decays rapidly after some finite time.

Comment: Allright thank you. I am particularly interested by the decay speed of the impulse response. Indeed, if I take the example of a signal $f(t)$ that is monochromatic (thus the ""real"" spectrum is infinitely sharp), it means that the output $S(t)$ will then vary over a duration $T$ which correspond to the support of $\chi$. So, I suppose that the function $\chi$ must have a pretty short support to explain the fact that by looking continuously we don't see its color changing. Would you agree with that ? Do you know where I could find the typical size of the support of those response function

Comment: @StarBucK I recommend looking at the references cited in the question and the answer underneath it.

Answer (score 1):

If we can observe a signal for a finite time, we can estimate its frequency approximately, with an uncertainty inversely proportional to the duration of the observationg.

As I understand it, the ear works by the sound waves vibrating certain small structures within the ear, which are resonant at different frequencies. These structures excite nerves that communicate the signal to the brain. If the sound wave is present long enough to excite the structure of the ear and produce a nervous signal to the brain, then we perceive a sound at the frequency associated with the particular structure that generated the nervous signal.

And the eyes work by light exciting chemicals in the rod and cone receptors in our eyes, again triggering a nervous signal to the brain. If there is sufficient light at a given frequency to produce a sufficient photochemical excitation to trigger the nervous signal, then our brain can perceive light. The mechanism by which signals from cone cells are used to produce the perception of color is a bit complicated, but to answer this question, suffice it to say if there is sufficient light present to excite a small number of cone cells, that is enough for us to perceive the light having a certain color.

But also be aware that our vision doesn't distinguish particular wavelengths of light. It only distinguishes the amount by which the light excites three different photoreceptors, which have peak response at three different frequencies, but which actually all have at least a small response pretty much across the whole visible spectrum.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think that my question is very closely related to your last paragraph. Let's forget about bio-aspect and think about the transfer function of a receptor. Does that mean that those sensor actually integrate the signal over a given time ? From causal linear systems we have $S(t)=\int_{-\infty}^t \chi(t-t') E(t') dt'$, which gives $S(\omega)=H(\omega) E(\omega)$. Looking at the transfer function of the detector I can access $\chi$ and thus deduce what is the integration time ?

Comment: @StarBucK, The fact that movies and television work (that we don't see the screen going dark between frames) tells you that yes, our vision has a low-pass filtering effect.

Comment: Allright thank you. Then in term of frequencies we are not directly sensitive to the frequency of the input but more precisely on the product $H(\omega)*E(\omega)$ (frequencies filtered). I would have a last question. I call $T$ the typical support of the function $\chi$ ($\chi \approx 1/\Delta \omega$ where $\Delta \omega$ is the frequency spread of $H(\omega)$). Would you agree that $T$ must be shorter than typical timescale of what we are aware of. What I mean is that if $T$ is too long, then we would see color changing by continuously looking at them (because the signal integration...

Comment: ...is not over. This question is probably more related to how we really perceive things, but considering that the way we are sensitive to audio/visual stimuli is a physical process I would say that it is a plausible condition. Would you agree ?

Answer (score -1):

Actually, your question is related to the precise details of how the body works, and has nothing to do with physics. The ear does not perform a Fourier transform. It is a long time since I studied it, but the biomechanics is quite complex. Certainly it has nothing to do with FTs. The ear contains multiple sensors sensitive to different frequencies. Iirc there are three separate mechanisms which recognise low medium and high frequencies. For high frequencies in the inner ear, hair cells are thought to resonate at different frequencies.

Comment: I'm not understanding. You say it has nothing to do with FTs and you talk about how hair cell resonate at different frequencies. As soon as you talk about frequency you talk about FT in an indirect way.

Comment: Not so. A filter is not an FT.

Comment: In my question I am not saying that the body **must directly** do a Fourier transform. What I say is that as we are sensitive to some frequencies in the spectrum, in an indirect way it does signal processing on frequencies. And as soon as we talk about frequency there is the notion of F.T implicitly (because the definition of a frequency is based on F.T). My question is to understand how we can be sensitive to given frequency in the spectrum as to access a given frequency a signal would have to be integrated on an infinite time. There must have some windowing process which I am trying to

Comment: ...understand here.

Comment: And I think the answer is given by @The Photon which is that the different receptor has some Fourier transfer function which are spread which means that the signal is integrated over a finite time (which plays the role of the averaging over a finite windows I was talking about)

Comment: The definition of frequency is based on a cyclic function, NOT the FT. The FT is a way of *calculating* frequency content, not *defining* it. @ThePhoton talks of resonators. I described sensors sensitive to particular frequencies, which is the same thing. In signal processing we would talk of filters, which are closely related mathematical analogues. No integration is taking place.

Comment: Well. If you want to talk about a spectrum you need the concept of F.T to define it. I could agree that for monochromatic signal you don't need it but in your answer you cannot avoid the concept.

Comment: If you think a question should be closed, which prevents answers from being made, then it doesn't make much sense to supply an answer. That essentially gives the impression of "I think I should be able to make an answer, but I don't think anyone else should be able to."

Comment: @StarBuck, the spectrum of a real audio signal is constantly changing, so obviously it is not given by the FT.

Comment: @BioPhysicist, that is not what happened. The OP was pressing for an answer as to why this question is not appropriate for this site, which is all I gave.

Comment: @BioPhysicist I will update my question later as you suggest.

Comment: @CharlesFrancis I'm sorry but what you say doesn't make sense. The Fourier transform requires to integrate the signal from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$. The spectrum does not change in time in a FT by the very definition of what a F.T is. It might change in time if you do not do a FT but some kind of windowed version of it.

Comment: In fact it is your understanding of the FT which does not make sense. Perhaps when you have studied it in mathematics, and had a career in signal processing (as I have), you will understand it better.

Comment: @CharlesFrancis I will stop the discussion here. What you are talking about is not FT but some time-frequency representation. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time%E2%80%93frequency_representation As explained on this article with a F.T you don't have any information about time (as the integration occurs on infinity).

Comment: Precisely. The FT gives you no time information, so it is trivially obvious that that is not how hearing works. That is exactly why your question has nothing to do with physics, or indeed any other branch or science.

Comment: You didn't vote to close then provide an answer?

Comment: @CharlesFrancis there is nothing "trivially obvious" in any of the things you answer which are either wrong, either so imprecise that they don't mean anything. You talk about a spectrum which by default for any physicist without more context mean the FT spectrum. If not you need to provide how you define a spectrum else it doesn't mean anything. I will edit tomorrow when I have time to focus on sensor and then give the example of eye/ear which is in the end a particular case of what sensor are. If you think it is not science to understand how ear and eye work then I don't know what to tell you

Comment: Allright I think we should stop the discussion here. Lets just say we dont agree. This is making both of us loose our time. Thanks.

Comment: Let's just say you don't agree with the mathematics or with any of the answers given. You have three answers telling you that the spectrum is the result of an array of resonators, or filters. The maths is quite different from the FT, which is not even mathematically defined as you have it without further constraints on the signal. Despite your accusations, I do not think many physicists are quite as ignorant as you claim.